# Should I be using Web Api Controller in This Situation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I working on a page where you can edit the whole page through the jquery [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) plugin. Once you make a change an ajax request is made and the change is saved to the database.

I am wondering if those ajax calls should be to a regular asp.net mvc controller or if I should make a new api controller and have all the requests go to that controller.

So if you imagine [this demo page](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) each one of those examples would cause an ajax request to the server.

The original page would load up through the mvc controller and I may have other ajax request going to this mvc controller to bring back partial views on demand but I am starting to think for all these "edit fields" they should be in a web api controller.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.
I haven't tried with x-editable but the point is:

When you have lots of actions returning JSON or when working with a screen that doesn’t have
an HTML part - you should try with web api.

So, if your back-end is essentially providing data services, then: **Yes**, use web api controller. It should be simpler than MVC.

Comment: Yea that's why I started to think web api for those actions might be better as I don't think anything will even be returned from the controller(the change is already on the html side). I am thinking though the page will have a mix as I am going to have an "add button" that will bring back a partial view with a form through ajax. This seems better then to have it a web api call that returns json and have to built the form from the json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should go for ASP.NET WEB API.

I checked the plugin link and saw the sample request/response, for example:

```
POST url = "/post"
name = "country"
value = "BT"
pk = "1"
RESPONSE: status = 200
--------------------------------------
```

ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.